# How to make multiply Drawing out of on Drawing cocoa touch class?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to create a "`Set`" game App and for that I need to build a view with many `subviews` which each of them contains one specific `Card` ( 3  green filled ovals,  or 1 red empty triangle etc.)

so I create a view that will contain all subviews(cards)

`let myView = UIView(myCGRect)`

now I want to put the first 12 Cards out of my Deck of Cards into that View

but my problem is I don't know how.

I already made a cocoa class called `CardView` that draws one image like an oval but only that oval will be drawn. (I used `UIBezierPath`)

so how can make like maybe an array of 81 cards of different triangles that appears 1 or 2 or 3 times with different colors etc. and safe them into an array in my `Viewcontroller` ?

is this even a good Idea or not?

I started `IOS` Programming 2 month ago so i'm absolutely  beginner in swift.

Comment: pls notice that I actually now how to add that in my superView like view.addSubview(mysubview).

Comment: so main problem is how to make all the different(81) views with just one drawing class

Comment: Your question is too broad. The community cannot develop the whole project for you. Once you have started on a solution, you can ask a specific question if  you have a problem with your code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: stackoverflow.com